# Many <img> Ids using the same routine

Tags: jquery

I have this code that copies the value of an `<img>` to the clicker's clipboard and provides a notification that the value has been copied. In the final version, many `<img>` with their own value (`id="me_too"`,`id="me_too"`,`id="me_too"`,...) should be copied to the clipboard and basically go through the same routine. I guess this is possible using arrays or loops? I'm quite new to jQuery and programming, so help would be very much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<p><img id="smiley" value=":)" src="..." />
<p><img id="me_too" value=";)" src="..." />
<p><img id="and_me" value=":D" src="..." />
<p><img id="and_me_too" value=":X" src="..." />

<p id="info_satz">&nbsp;</p>
```

jQuery:

```
        jQuery('#smiley').on('click', function() {
            var value = jQuery(this).attr('value');

            copyToClipboard(value);
            jQuery('#info_satz').hide().html(value + '  copied to clipboard.').fadeIn('normal');
        });

        function copyToClipboard(value) {
            var $tmpInput = $('<input>');
            $tmpInput.val(value);
            jQuery('body').append($tmpInput);
            $tmpInput.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            $tmpInput.remove();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a class rather than ID's.

Give each image a class, e.g. `yourClass`

`<img id="smiley" class="yourClass" value=":)" src="..." />`

Than select all the image elements using that class, and add the event listener:

`jQuery('.yourClass').on('click', function(){ ... }`

Your code is already relative to the element that clicked it (since you use `this` to select the value) so the rest should work as expected.

Full example of your modified code:

```js
jQuery('.yourClass').on('click', function() {
  var value = jQuery(this).attr('value');

  copyToClipboard(value);
  jQuery('#info_satz').hide().html(value + '  copied to clipboard.').fadeIn('normal');
});

function copyToClipboard(value) {
  var $tmpInput = $('<input>');
  $tmpInput.val(value);
  jQuery('body').append($tmpInput);
  $tmpInput.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  $tmpInput.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img id="smiley" class="yourClass" value=":)" src="..." />
</p>
<p>
  <img id="me_too" class="yourClass" value=";)" src="..." />
</p>
<p>
  <img id="and_me" class="yourClass" value=":D" src="..." />
</p>
<p>
  <img id="and_me_too" class="yourClass" value=":X" src="..." />
</p>

<p id="info_satz">&nbsp;</p>
```